# Memory Leak Grails application in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, memory-leaks

I have a grails (v2.1.5) app in production, it works fine and i can redeploy without problems, but i have updated the app (a few changes), when I deploy the new war,  i get a memory leak error, the server starts but the app doesn´t work (the page in the browser is only a withe page), I tried to reboot the instance, stop all services,....

I can redeploy only the old war. How could i fix this problem?

Thanks.

The errors:

> Mar 09, 2014 4:02:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>
> Mar 09, 2014 4:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
>
> Mar 09, 2014 4:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>
> Mar 09, 2014 4:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>
> Mar 09, 2014 4:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@61783b69] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>
> Mar 09, 2014 4:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [com.padelsix.SecRole.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

The web application [/services] appears to have started a thread named `[net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@37ce6a10]` but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
The solution, in our groovy based spring web app that uses annotation based configuration, was to register the *net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.ShutdownListener* class with the context in our class that extends *WebApplicationInitializer* via an overridden `onStartup()` method, something like this:

```
import net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.ShutdownListener
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer
...

public class CustomWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
...

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    ...
    createContext(...)
    ...
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class... annotatedClasses) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()
    context.register(annotatedClasses)
    context.register(ShutdownListener)
    return context
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is not the potential memory leaks, it is the first part of the log:

> Mar 09, 2014 4:02:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>
> Mar 09, 2014 4:07:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

The error "SEVERE: Error listenerStart" usually means that there was an error in a servlet context listener (run on startup) that prevented the webapp to start.

Look for errors both in `catalina.out` and `localhost.<date>.log`. You may need to enable additional logging to find the root cause of this error. Google for "SEVERE: Error listenerStart" and look for specific instructions for your version of Tomcat.